# ERROR in Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of undefined

Tags: angular

Buen día, alguien sabe como resolver este problema que tengo sobre ruteo de angula?

Lo que quiero hacer es: Como mi objeto para crear una nueva ruta en angular se volvió algo complejo, quería ponerlo en una interfaz, entonces en el constructor de ese objeto podía realizar cosas comunes para todos los objetos que creo en el app.route.ts

Al implementar mi interfaz, que no hace absolutamente nada complejo, el compilador me da el error: **ERROR in Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of undefined**

Aquí el código que si anda, sin implementar mi interfaz (repito, esto si anda, y no me trae ningún problema):

*app.route.ts:*

```
const APP_ROUTES = [
    {path: 'rolListado', component: RolListadoComponent, canActivate: [RouteFilterService], data: {rolesHabilitados: [Shared.ROL_ADMIN]}},
];

export const APP_ROUTING = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES, {useHash: true});
```

Esto es lo que quería implementar que no me anda y me genera el error mencionado anteriormente. Que seria lo mismo pero con una interfaz:

*app.route.ts:*

```
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    new Ruta('rolListado', RolListadoComponent),
];

export const APP_ROUTING = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES, {useHash: true});
```

*ruta.interfaz.ts:*

```
export class Ruta {

    path;
    component;
    canActivate;
    data;

    constructor(path, component, roles?) {
        this.path = path;
        this.component = component;
        this.canActivate = [RouteFilterService];
        this.data = {rolesHabilitados: [Shared.ROL_ADMIN]};
        if (roles) {
            this.data.rolesHabilitados.concat(roles);
        }
    }
}
```

Aquí una captura del error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quería implementar esta interfaz ya que como tengo muchas rutas era muchísimo el codigo, el app.route.ts quedaba con muchísimo código que uno veía que se repite en todas las rutas que uno va agregando

Cabe mencionar que estoy usando la ultima versión de angular

Se les ocurre alguna solución para arreglar este problema? Desde ya, gracias

Pd: no tengo en ninguna parte del proyecto una clase o propiedad llamada "loadChildren", estoy completamente seguro. He realizado un find en todo el proyecto y ninguna coincidencia. Y jamas creé una clase o propiedad con ese nombre